# Basement water intrusion water supply line -- Is this something that can be fixed DIY or does it require foundation repair?

Tags: water, leak, foundation

I woke up this morning and found wet carpet in the corner of my basement, which is a bummer. I know the first thing that comes to mind is foundation damage, but I'm hoping that's not the case here -- I did some looking and found that the at least some water appears to be coming from around the incoming water supply. I'd like to fix that and see if I ever see the water again before I do something like call a foundation repair company.

It looks like there is some sealant around the pipe, but I could see after several years this sealant coming loose and allowing water intrusion. Is fixing that something as easy as digging out the old sealant and adding something new, or is it more nuanced?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Foundation leaks is always recommended to seal from the outside for a lifetime permanent repair.  Inside repairs will need something much better than expanding foam.  Something like epoxy injection, not sure.